# Creating Dropdown Using mySQL but getting error

Tags: php

So basically I have a database and inside that I have a table named drivers which is structured as:

Drivers:
id 
forename
surname
nationality 
team_id

Now I want to pull the Forename and Surname in a HTML Form. I need a submit button and a drop down list input. The drop down will contain the names of the drivers and the form will submit via a GET method.

How would I possibly go about doing this? This is what I have so far however it doesn't seem to work and I haven't

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Write out our query.
$link=mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,dbname));
$result = mysqli_query( "SELECT * FROM Drivers");
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

$dropdown = "<select name='Drivers'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['forename']}'>{$row['surname']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $dropdown;
```

?>

I'm quite new to PHP so apologies for such a noob question.

Comment: 1.) What's the error 2.) You're mixing mysql **i** with `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /proj/co323/php/rn207/public_html/try.php on line 11

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","dbname");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Write out our query.
    $link=mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,dbname);
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Drivers");
    // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
    $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

    $dropdown = "<select name='Drivers'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['forename']}'>{$row['surname']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown = "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown;
?>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Problem came from here:

```
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

**FIXED**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, just to let you know that I am still getting an error on line 12 telling me 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 12
It would be great if this would be solved. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just change this line     $link=mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,dbname); You forget to remove latest  ")" - If answer helped you thank's to VOTE to the answer ;)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the editing .. I just noticed that as soon as I add my database details, the line 12 seems to be giving me a T VARIABLE error and its only after i put in me database information.. So what could be causing this error??

Comment: Hi, I already tried adjusting the spacing on line 12 but it just does not seem to get rid of the error once I put in my database information giving me the same error (T VARIABLE) amd also using that code above it has the same problem in line 12.. what could be causing this error?? .. Any other solutions???

Comment: Must change this line:     $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Yes I have changed that too and used your code above and the same error comes up

Comment: Please fix this as it would be such a great help!

Comment: Copy paste new code, i modified it too and let me see the next error ! if dont work probably the error came from your databse, verify if you have the table's name with all columns.

Comment: hi, Its giving an error in the While loop statement now o what could be wrong there now?   
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  on line 16